# How to handle Deprecated Remote-Address when running unit tests

Tags: scala, unit-testing, akka-http

I am upgrading older project to Akka-Http 10.2.10 and see that header `Remote-Address` is marked as deprecated.

In my tests I require setting of remote-address as the authentication side on backend server requires this.

If I add header to my unit test call (shown below) then test executes as expected.

```
Get("/").withHeaders(`Remote-Address`(RemoteAddress(InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress)))
```

I don't have any options on the backend server side and have seen prior posts that akka http can't handle the RawHeader in test so I am at a loss on options.

Ideas?/Suggestions

Comment: Not sure if I get you right. It might be an option to use the https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.2.10/akka/http/scaladsl/model/AttributeKeys$.html as stated in the migration guide https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/migration-guide/migration-guide-10.2.x.html#x-real-ip-now-takes-precedence-over-remote-address-in-extractclientip - is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Regarding what you refer to - is this not for access the header and not for setting the header. In my tests I need to set the header for remote-address - maybe I am missing something but I don't see how this helps setting/adding the remote-address to the http-test GET.

Comment: I am referring to the mentioned deprecated class which in its documentation points to the above mentioned attributes. What kind of deprecation are you referring to in the realm of setting a header value? Can you provide a link